# How to generate all N digits number in ruby?

Tags: ruby, numbers

If i give n=5.The answer should be 10000 to 99999.
If n=2 Then answer should be 10 to 99.
How to do it?

Comment: where is your code, have you tried anything????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) to generate this numbers:

```
(10**n...10**(n+1)).to_a
#=> [100, 101, 102, 103, ... 998, 999]
```

A Range with three dots `...` excludes the end value.